# sqlite constraint exception primary key must be unique

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have 3 tables

Table 1 : Member - To store every information about the member,

Attribute : MemberUsername(PK), MemberPassword

Table 2 : MsGroup - To store every registered group

Attribute : GroupId(PK), GroupName, GroupDescription

Table 3 : MsGroupDetail - To store list of every username in every group

Attribute : GroupId(PK,FK), MemberUsername(PK,FK)

My Query for Creating that 3 tables :

```
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MS_MEMBER + " ("
                + MEMBER_USERNAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
                + MEMBER_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + MEMBER_EMAIL
                + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MS_GROUP + " ("
                + GROUP_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + GROUP_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + GROUP_DESCRIPTION
                + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MS_GROUP_DETAIL + " ("
                + GROUP_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + MEMBER_USERNAME
                + " TEXT,  FOREIGN KEY (" + MEMBER_USERNAME
                + ") REFERENCES " + MS_MEMBER + "(" + MEMBER_USERNAME
                + "), FOREIGN KEY (" + GROUP_ID + ") REFERENCES "
                + MS_GROUP + "(" + GROUP_ID + "));");
```

I have successfully make some code to create member, create group, but the problem is I failed to create a query to invite/add a new member to a group (Failed to insert to MsGroupDetail)

This is the syntax for adding GroupMember

```
public void addGroupMember(String groupId, String username) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put(GROUP_ID, groupId);
    cv2.put(MEMBER_USERNAME, username);
    ourDatabase.insert(MS_GROUP_DETAIL, null, cv2);
}
```

And this is the syntax to see the list of my Groups

```
public String[] fetchGroupName(String username) {
    int i = 0;

    String Query = "SELECT " + GROUP_NAME + " From " + MS_GROUP
            + " a INNER JOIN " + MS_GROUP_DETAIL + " b ON a." + GROUP_ID
            + "=b." + GROUP_ID + " WHERE " + MEMBER_USERNAME + "=?";
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(Query, new String[] { username });
    String groupName[] = new String[c.getCount()];
    int iGroupName = c.getColumnIndex(GROUP_NAME);

    c.moveToFirst();
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        groupName[i] = c.getString(iGroupName);
        i++;
    }

    c.close();
    return groupName;
}
```

Everytime I invite a new member/adding to MsGroupDetail table, I failed to insert it to MsGroupDetail and the log cat said  : "SQLite Constraint Exception, primary key must be unique"

*nb : My MsGroupDetail is once again to list every member within a group,

I have tested the same concept in Sql Server Management Studio 2008 and It worked, aI dont know any better concept than what I've coded above,

Can you guys please tell me is there any solution for this?

Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `GROUP_ID` is not unique.  If you have two members in group 1, your table will have two entries --

```
1, Member 1
1, Member 2
```

By specifying "PRIMARY KEY" on `GROUP_ID` you are stating it will be unique.  You need different primary key. In android, it is common to use "_id", something like --

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MS_GROUP_DETAIL + " ("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + GROUP_ID + " INTEGER, " + MEMBER_USERNAME
                + " TEXT,  FOREIGN KEY (" + MEMBER_USERNAME
                + ") REFERENCES " + MS_MEMBER + "(" + MEMBER_USERNAME
                + "), FOREIGN KEY (" + GROUP_ID + ") REFERENCES "
                + MS_GROUP + "(" + GROUP_ID + "));");
```

Comment: Is the "_id" always be the primary key on every table?

Comment: If `_id` is never used, it's not necessary to add it in the first place.

Comment: @JuliusLeo Some Android components (e.g., list views) reqire a column named `_id` in certain queries. However, you will not use such a query for *this* table, and when you are displaying a list of, e.g., groups, you can always rename the `GROUP_ID` column to `_id` while querying.

Comment: @CL is right, if you don't need a primary key, you don't need to add it. "_id" is not required to be the primary key it is convention that some adapters use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses, I am quite new in programming, so I am trying to catch up with what you were trying to say, every table needs a primary key and it must be unique, because my GroupId is not unique enough, so the _id is replacing it as the PK,,

Comment: and about "if you don't need a primary key, you dont need to add it". Is it okay to have a non-PK attribute within a table?

Comment: @JuliusLeo In sqlite, the primary key is optional. You can have at most one and its values must be unique.  You can define the table without it.