# Access email-id along with name and phone number from contact list in Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-contacts, contactscontract

Here I am accessing name and phone number from mobile and uploading to server. I am not facing any problem in this. I have made some modifications  to access email also. But I am not able to fetch the email. In place of email it is displaying phone number. I have used `System.out.print` to check the details. Here is my code.

**DisplayContact**

```
public class DisplayContact extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    //ArrayList to store name and phone number
    List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> email1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma ;
    Button select;

    private String vault;

    public static final String kvault = "vault_no";
    public static final String kname = "name";
    public static final String kphone = "phone";
    public static final String kemail = "email";
    public static final String kcontacts = "contacts";

    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myloginapp";
    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://oursite.com/contacts_1.php";

    Cursor phones;
    String[] PROJECTION;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(ProfileLogin.SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        vault = sharedPreferences.getString(ProfileLogin.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");

        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // adding
        select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder name2 = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder phone2 = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder email2 = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

                {
                    if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                    {
                        checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append(phno1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append(email1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                         name2.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                         phone2.append(phno1.get(i).toString());
                         email2.append(email1.get(i).toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
                uploadImage();
            }
        });
    }

    public void uploadImage(){

        final String vault_no = vault;

        class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(DisplayContact.this,"Please wait...","uploading",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Successfully Saved")){
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(CollegeDetails.this,Work.class);
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayContact.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayContact.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                //RegisterUserClass rh = new RegisterUserClass();
                HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();

                JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray();
                for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)
                {
                    try {
                        JSONObject contact = new JSONObject();

                        contact.put(kphone, phno1.get(i).toString());
                        contact.put(kname, name1.get(i).toString());
                        contact.put(kemail, email1.get(i).toString());
                        contact.put(kvault, vault_no);
                        contacts.put(contact);

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("the JSONRes ARRAY is" + contacts);

                param.put(kcontacts,contacts.toString());
               return rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, param);

            }
        }
        UploadImage u = new UploadImage();
        u.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(DisplayContact.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){


            //fetches contacts from the phone contact list and displays in ascending order
            phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
            contactsdisplay();

        } else {

            requestForLocationPermission();
        }
    }

    private void requestForLocationPermission()
    {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(DisplayContact.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
        {
        }
        else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DisplayContact.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    getAllContacts(DisplayContact.this.getContentResolver());
                    contactsdisplay();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public  void contactsdisplay() {

        //Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME ));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String emailid = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            System.out.println(".................."+name+ "" +phoneNumber+ "" +emailid);
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
            email1.add(emailid);
        }

        phones.close();
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv,tv2;
        CheckBox cb;
        MyAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)DisplayContact.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            tv2= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.email_id);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_id);
            cb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv.setText("Name :" + name1.get(position));
            tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
            tv2.setText("Email id :"+ email1.get(position));
            cb.setTag(position);
            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }
        public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    }

}
```

I think I am missing something in this part it seems.

`phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");`

Comment: no, you need to use `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI` uri

Comment: in this line..?`phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");`

Comment: did i say `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`? i said you need `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI`

Comment: okay..i will check

Comment: i am not getting..where do i need to use `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI uri `

Comment: @pskink can u please see this [question..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503378/null-pointer-exception-while-uploading-contacts-to-server)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :--**

```
private String retriveContactEmail(Uri uriContact) {
    String useremail = null;
    // getting contacts ID
    Cursor cursorID = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uriContact, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID}, null, null, null);

    if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {
        contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    cursorID.close();
    // get email and type
    Cursor emailCur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contactID}, null);
    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
        // This would allow you get several email addresses
        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
        String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
        String emailType = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
        useremail = email;
    }
    emailCur.close();

    return useremail;
}
```

Comment: can it be possible to make some modifications to get the email id along with the phone number and name..?i dont want it separately..i mean is there any possibility to fetch from this line `phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");`

Comment: i don't know but by this way you 100% get email from contacts

Comment: okay.but i need to bind those email id along with name and phone number..thats the main motto behind this question..

Comment: you can do as well by this.

Comment: can u suggest me how to do that one..?

Comment: String emailid = retriveContactEmail(uriContact);

Comment: googling about this you getting very perfect